# sharing object in multiple run of spring integration flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to share a variable or object, amongst spring integration components such that once the flow reaches splitter, after that the variable/object should be accessible for each splitted flow. 
Please suggest how can we do it??

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that in the Messaging stateless world is headers. So you should use a `HeaderEnricher` to store your object in the custom header before splitting. This way all the splitted items will get the same headers. But you should keep in mind if your object is mutable, any changes in any item process will affect all other items. Just because the object is the same.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher

Comment: Hi Artem,


Hi Artem,

Thanks for that answer.
What if I want to store the  variable after splitting, in one of the splitted flows and want to access it in other splitted flows. 
Will it still work if I add into header in one of the splitted flows?
I am fine with the object being editable in each splitted flow.

Comment: Well, then it's not about headers. You need to use some shared store for that purpose. The simple way is `AtomicReference` bean. Another is like a `Map` to store and get objects by key. For more reliable use-cases people use external data base services.